UIA text selection and caret position
TLDR: I am trying to programmatically select text in Windows UIA applications (notepad, MSWord, Visual Studio), in such a way that I need to be able to specify whetehr caret stays at the beginning or at the end of selection. And I can't find a way to do so via UIA or via any other API.
I am blind and I use NVDA screenreader. I am rewriting word navigation (control+left/rightArrow) and word selection (control+shift+left/rightArrow) commands - I am adding more flexibility to them. Word navigation works fine - setting caret position is easy. However I am running into big problems when trying to set selection.
The problem
When you're selecting something forward via control+shift+rightArrow, then the caret is supposed to stay at the end of selection, while when selecting backward, then the caret should stay at the beginning. Sometimes it's called the active end of selection - whichever end contains caret. Being able to set the active point of selection is crucial - if specified wrong then consecutive select by word or select by character commands are going to behave very weirdly.
For IAccessible2 and TOM it can be done easily. But UIA is being stubborn and doesn't let me do that.
Question 1: how to select a range in notepad and put caret at the front of selection?
I haven't figured out a way. By default caret is placed at the end. But here is my best attempt below.
Using NVDA Python console: Let's try to select something:
> import UIAHandler
> r = focus.UIATextPattern.GetSelection().getElement(0).clone()

Now r is IUIAutomationTextRange. Let's try to select a character:
> UIAUnit=UIAHandler.NVDAUnitsToUIAUnits['character']
> r.MoveEndpointByUnit(UIAHandler.TextPatternRangeEndpoint_End, UIAUnit, 1)

And try to select it:
> r.Select()

Now we can verify in notepad that a character has indeed been selected, and the cursor has been placed at the end of selection. You can deduce that by pressing shift+right/leftArrow - the behavior depends on which end of selection is active.
The function IUIAutomationTextRange::Select() doesnt' take any input arguments as stated here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtextrange-select
Now I also found IUIAutomationTextRange::AddToSelection() method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtextrange-addtoselection
In the best style of Microsoft documentation the description is as useless as it can be - they don't have any indication as to the difference between AddToSelection() and Select() methods. However some more investigation revealed this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-usingtextrangeobjects
That contains somewhat cryptic sentence:

If a text-based control supports text insertions, calling IUIAutomationTextRange::AddToSelection or RemoveFromSelection on a degenerate text range in the control moves the insertion point but does not select any text.

Sounds promising, but when I try to call it:
>>> r.AddToSelection()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
>  File "monkeyPatches\comtypesMonkeyPatches.pyc", line 32, in __call__
> _ctypes.COMError: (-2146233079, None, (None, None, None, 0, None))

Whatever this error means I couldn't figure it out, it appears that the method is not really implemented.
Question 2: how to figure out which end of current selection is active?
I haven't figured that out either. Reading NVDA source code it always assumes that the cursor is at the beginning, which is wrong.
Consulting IUIAutomationTextPattern  docuemntation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtextpattern
The only relevant method seems to be getSelection(). It returns an array that contains only a single selection, with no indication on whetehr the cursor is at the start or at the end.
Question 3: Is there a way to set selection via another API?
As far as I can tell notepad really only works with UIA, but wondering if I'm missing something and there is perhaps another way to set selection that would work better?
Question 4: How to provide feedback to Microsoft regarding these UIA flaws?
Assuming that I didn't miss anything obvious and that there is really no way in UIA to get and set active end of selection, does anybody know a good way to provide feedback to Microsoft? Like perhaps create a github issue or something? I realize that chances of anyone lifting a finger within Microsoft are negligible, but it would be good to at least document that. And it would be good to have a page to point my users to when they complain that word selection doesn't work in Notepad.
Thanks!
I already described above what I tried and I would expect there must be a way to tell at which end of selection caret currently resides. And I would expect there must be a way to set selection and put caret in the front.
